# How can I convert a `List<Map<String,String>>` to a `Set<Map<String,String>>` in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

I made Hindi Vocabulary app using flutter.

I want to know how to convert a `List<Map<String,String>>` to a `Set<Map<String,String>>`.

Because if users add some words which they want to remind, they can add this in unmemory list. But if they see the same section, the words they want to add are overlapped. So I want to terminate the overlapping words using the set.

Here is my code:

```dart
class unMemory_words {
  String words;
  String word_class;
  String mean;
  String example_hindi;
  String example_korean;
  Map<String, String> _saved_word_list;
    
  static List<Map<String, String>> list = new List<Map<String, String>>();
    
  unMemory_words(
    String words,
    String word_class,
    String mean,
    String example_hindi,
    String example_korean,
  ) {
    this.words = words;
    this.word_class = word_class;
    this.mean = mean;
    this.example_hindi = example_hindi;
    this.example_korean = example_korean;
    
    _saved_word_list = {
      'hindi': this.words,
      'case': this.word_class,
      'meaning': this.mean,
      'hindi_example_sentence': this.example_hindi,
      'korean_example_sentence': this.example_korean
    };
    list.add(_saved_word_list);
  }
}
```

Thank you!

Comment: You'll be using your Map values as elements of a Set.  Since the keys of a set are checked using ==, which by default does not include deep equality, you could clearly end up with two entries with the "same" Map, since they will have been constructed as two separate objects.  Not sure why you want a Set here.  Perhaps you want a map keyed by some unique string in your maps, to make a Map<String,Map<String,String>>.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this by this way:

```dart
final list = <Map<String, String>>[];
final set = list.toSet();
```